sciplot c++ drawWithVecs
I am trying to use sciplot in a C++17 framework to plot a vector field. I found a function called drawWithVecs but I am not sure how to use it or whether it even is suited to this purpose. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?
Please see this example from matplotlib for plotting a vector field.

to plot a vector field -- what do you mean?

@3CxEZiVlQ added an example from matplotlib.

Gnuplot itself can certainly draw vector fields.  See for example the demo https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_6.0/vector.html     I do not know what sciplot library commands are needed in order to wrap that.

Thanks @Ethan. I was hoping that since gnuplot can draw vector fields sciplot has something similar.
